# Cannot populate Spinner with data from remote server database

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am trying to figure out how to populate a Spinner (eventually a whole form of spinners) with data taken from a remote MySQL database. I have read hundreds of examples and tried to replicate them all but to no avail.

I have been working with this example from http://www.mickyjay.co.uk/blog/?p=679
I was never able to get it to work but it seems the most promising out of the lot.

QUESTIONS:

1) Do I need to use a JDBC bridge to connect to the server ? (I was reading that Android does not come with a library to connect to a remote server).

2) I am not looking for someone to do this for me. If anyone has any links to resources that are CLEAR and well documented. I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have MySql database it's good to use PHP to connect to database and send result back to android using JSON response. Android and PHP both support JSON. You can then read JSON and process data as you want in android side. You use HTTP request to run php script. Take a look at this tutorail that shows how to use android, PHP and MySql all together http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/